# How to create keyboard shortcut from xfce terminal

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce4-terminal

So i want to run flameshoot with keyboard shortcut. In terminal i can do `flameshoot gui`, but i want to know how to do this with keyboard shortcut. How to add command to shortcut?

btw i use xfce4 environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every desktop environment has a facility to define custom keyboard shortcuts, typically somewhere in the Settings. Through a dialog, you can define a label, the command to run (`flameshot gui`) and then a shortcut key that will trigger the command.

This is basic functionality in a desktop environment. You are expected to take some time to learn your desktop environment, so read the help files for the details on where this is found and how this works in the XFCE desktop environment.

Comment: thanks for the tip